# Masonry CSS order

Tags: php, css, jquery-masonry

i'm pulling my images from my DB and trying bring the sort them to list accross rather than up and down. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

[Screenshot of Current Output](http://gopro30.com/gopro30/question1.jpg)

My CSS:

```
#myContent {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 0px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0px;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 0px;
    width: 900px;
}

#myContent img{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 90%;
}
```

My HTML and PHP

```
<ul id="myContent"> 
<div id="postedComments">

<?php 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stories ORDER BY pid ASC limit 0 , 5"); 

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$pid = $data['pid'];
$photo_url = $data['photo_url'];
echo "<div class='postedComment' id=\"$pid \">

<img src='$photo_url'>

<p>pid: $pid</p>

<hr />

</div>" ;

 }
?>

</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: A lot of that code is deprecated/not recommended like `center` and `br`. Try stripping everything out and just `float:left;` the images. This will make them all align across and when they don't fit, go to the next line

Comment: ok just updated my php to mysql_fetch_array, stripped the css and added float:left; but result is not aligning on the next row

Comment: They wont align unless you use masonry(jquery plugin) or add containers

Comment: the problem with masonry jquery plugin is that it doesnt seem to work well with my infinite scroll php code. It appends the newly loaded item to the top of the page. That's why im trying with only CSS.

Comment: CSS can't nicely align an unknown number of elements with varying heights

Comment: @Hector jQuery masonry should append to bottom of page. Are you using this code: `var $boxes = $( boxMaker.makeBoxes() ); $container.append( $boxes ).masonry( 'appended', $boxes );` ? Check it out here: http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html

Comment: @Inrbob yes i know of that option but when i say append i mean that newly fetched items overlap the first loaded items. I know its because of my php infinite scroll code, again which is why im trying it without the jquery

Comment: In other words is there a way to sort them across using Javascript, without resorting to masonry, i've tried vanilla masonry as well as others like woo mark etc and none seem to work well with my php infinite scroll code

Comment: I'd suggest you need to try using a different infinite scroll that maybe works with Masonry :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yourThanks guys, for anyone else who may run into this problem, try using http://philipbjorge.github.com/Infinite-Social-Wall/

Philip did a great job at achieving this. If you are an advanced developer you can download his source files and look though his logic. Alternatively you can remove the entire section where the social arrays are being called and just use the database to populate the new items.

Answer (score 0):

use "float:left" on the images you want to be in a single line.  Make sure to use something like this after all the images, so your HTML after the images will be functional:

```
.clear{
clear:both;
height:1px;
margin-bottom:-1px;
}

<div>
//Your pictures
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```